# user-generated XML, cross compatibility encoding

Tags: php, xml, encoding, formatting

So my application has a form where users input text, and the text is stored in CDATA tags in an XML file. I've noticed the input sent from some users' computers can be saved in the XML just fine, but input from other users' computers causes problems. I suspect that this has something to do with encoding.

Here is one user's [entry](http://psirup.com/articles/Siegerkranz/The%20faults%20of%20Communism%20.xml).

And here is [another's](http://psirup.com/articles/S1nus/The%20war%20between%20chechnya%20and%20russia.xml):

When I do:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
echo $xml->body;
```

Only the latter of the two examples works. Could someone please explain why?

EDIT: The first one has 'encoding="us-ascii"' because it produced a ton of errors with 'UTF-8'

Answer (score 0):

The first example's encoding is declared to be "us-ascii" while it actually contains non-ascii character “ in several places.
You should either use UTF-8 or filter out non-ascii characters.

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried UTF-8 in the first one. It produced a bunch of errors. It didn't even produce a valid XML file until I changed the encoding to us-ascii